# Dropwizard as a non blocking task execution component

Tags: java, dropwizard

I'm in the process of evaluating [dropwizard](http://dropwizard.io/) for a mission critical component of our production system.

What I need to implement is a command line tool with RESTful support(there is little need to provide REST API, I need mostly to communicate with external API systems for B2B), logging dependency injection and some short of non blocking I/O operations for maximum performance.

My question is if someone has experience with the particular framwork being ready for a production system and some alternative solutions of a lightweight non blocking operations (Something like Celery on Python)

Finally, does Dropwizard supports java 1.8?

Many thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Dropwizard is essentially a bunch of frameworks packaged together. You probably want to have a look at each of these. It doesn't come with non-blocking IO (unless you count Jetty), but tbh your description sounds a bit odd; if you want to *call* RESTful APIs you don't need dropwizard, it's for providing RESTful APIs. Also non-blocking IO is primarily good for high concurrency. If you call external APIs with high concurrency, usually you end up DOSing them.

Comment: Thank you for your replay, yes you are right I need some of the frameworks provided which are already tuned for me like coda hale, logback etc. I was wondering if it was able to provide/help with an integration of a Non blocking IO infrastructure. Additionally,  will have to hit an external API concurrently and as fast as I can but I have time restrictions on the destination side so I will not end up DoS-ing them.

Comment: It's not gonna help you adding non-blocking IO (it also notably doesn't have DI). Also, trust me if you hit them as fast as you can with high concurrency it will def. result in a DOS attack like situation (and it will also degrade the total performance anyways, even if they manage to cope with the load; i.e. there is nothing to gain from doing that).

Answer (score 0):

[dropwizard-sundial](https://github.com/timmolter/dropwizard-sundial) lets you schedule jobs in dropwizard. The github README has more sample but here's a quick sneak peak:

```
@CronTrigger(cron = "0/5 * * * * ?")
public class SampleJob extends org.knowm.sundial.Job {
  @Override
  public void doRun() throws JobInterruptException {
    // Do something interesting...
  }
}
```

What it does is at the time of initializing your dropwizard application, sundial will drop in and start its scheduler. Then you can configure tasks via package in yaml, tasks, xml. Also the admin task it registed could be used to manage jobs (create/trigger/etc).

One thing to notice is that dropwizard-sundial package itself includes a set of dropwizard-core and dropwizard-util. Very likely you'll find it conflicts with the version which would cause `NoClassDefException` or `NoMethodFoundException`. My solution is to exclude from dropwizard-sundial and use your own one.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.knowm</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-sundial</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
                <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
                <artifactId>dropwizard-util</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```